# Can't get rid of margin, already set the margin to 0

Tags: html, css

There is a margin on the div elements `id="textbox"` and `id="visualizer"`. I have already set the margin to 0 in the CSS, but it wouldn't go away. You can still see the margin in the inspect window. I have experimented with changing the display types in the container div, etc but the problem still persist. You can find the code attached in the link below:

https://jsfiddle.net/kshatriiya/fhbqqmxc/1/

```
<div id="play-area">
    <div id="play-area-overlay">
        <div id="textbox">
            <h2>
                Welcolme. 

            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="visualizer">   

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#play-area {

position: relative;
width: 100vw;
height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;


}

#play-area-overlay {

position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;

}

#textbox {

height: 100%;
width: 400px;
margin: 0px;

}

#visualizer {

height: 100%;
width: 50%;
margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Did you factor that h2 will have a default margin or padding? that's probably it. i didn't check the fiddle.

Comment: I have tried setting the margin and padding of h2 to 0 as well, it didn't help. In the inspect too, the margin sits on the mentioned div elements themselves although their margins are set to 0 as well in the css.

Comment: Your textbox h2 has a margin

Comment: I have tried getting rid of the h2 element altogether but the problem still persists unfortunately. You can actually inspect the margin on the divs in the jsfiddle even without the h2 element

Comment: Can it be that you're not seeing a margin, but the space created by making the div's 50% width?

Comment: Don't forget the h4 above as well. I checked your fiddle. removing the margins does change things for me but I don't know what you will consider to be correct. The h4 is only in the fiddle. You should update so the code is identical

Comment: #textbox h2 {
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
margin: 0px;
}

Comment: I just looked in Chrome's inspect tool, and if you change width to 100%, it looks fine. So my guess is the tool deceptively uses the same color for the white space gap, as it does for an actual margin.

Comment: Hello, the h4 sits in the navbar and to me doesn't appear to interfere with the two div elements below in separate container div. I'd to be able to put "textbox" and "visualizer" divs side by side in the flexbox container. The margin is preventing me from doing so.

If I remove the width from both divs, the divs default their width back to 100%. If I define the width to a fix number or percentage, it gives me the margin.

Comment: @kshatriiya See my answer below for an explanation of why the divs are not laying side-by-side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not margin you're seeing in the inspector, but negative space because your elements are set to use `width: 50%;`. By default, `div` elements are `block-level`, which means they will start on new lines. Floating will change this behavior.

Add `float: left` to your CSS (and you can consolidate the elements like such), and they'll fit together side-by-side to form 100% width.

```
#textbox,
#visualizer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
}
```

Here's a full example with the elements colored so you can see them next to each other:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var navbar = document.querySelector("#navbar");
  var Yoffset = this.pageYOffset;

  if (Yoffset > 0) {
    navbar.style.borderBottom = "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)";
  } else {
    navbar.style.borderBottom = "";
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
#main-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}
#mainscreen {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#navbar-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 68.53px;
}
#navbar {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: #112D34;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 1;
}
#navbar #logo {
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
#navlinks ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
#navlinks ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
#play-area {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#play-area-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#textbox,
#visualizer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
}
#textbox {
  background: lightblue;
}
#visualizer {
  background: lightgreen;
}
#playlist-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<section id="main-container">
  <div id="navbar-container">
    <div id="navbar">
      <div id="logo">
        <h4><SPAN>V</SPAN>ibe<span>C</span>iti</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="navlinks">
        <ul>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Playlist</li>
          <li>Gallery</li>
          <li>Portfolio</li>
          <li>
            <button>Contact</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainscreen">
    <div id="play-area">
      <div id="play-area-overlay">
        <div id="textbox">
          <h2>Welcolme.</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="visualizer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="playlist-container">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Setting box-sizing: border-box; may help with cross-browser issues too. Maybe OP thinks margin is the issue while it's the border pushing the next element down, so I mention it just in case.

Comment: @DavidDylan Agreed that border-box is good practice, but the elements in question do not have a border.

Comment: That worked magic! Thank you. I did wanted to avoid using floats and instead position things with flexbox, any idea why it causes this issue? 

I still do have a minor problem, the h2 element is slightly offscreen, I can fix this with margin-left but I wonder why this happens.

http://imgur.com/a/6CxKK

Comment: I think some older browsers reserve border space regardless. Could be wrong. :)

Comment: @DavidDylan Not that I know of!

Comment: @kshatriiya Looks like you're scrolled over in your screenshot (see the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom). Also, you did not have `flexbox` implemented in your example. You would need to put `display: flex` on the element `#play-area-overlay` and remove the floats.

Comment: Edit: Nvm about the h2 part above, for some reason the divs are set to be wider than the viewport width. Maybe width: 100vw is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the use of flexbox, it is supported in all modern browsers and the sollution with float left is only needed if you rely on browsers older than IE10
So the releant changes are:

```
#play-area-overlay {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

#textbox, #visualizer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

And here is your snippet with the display flex changes and also coloring of the two containers:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var navbar = document.querySelector("#navbar");
  var Yoffset = this.pageYOffset;

  if (Yoffset > 0) {
    navbar.style.borderBottom = "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)";
  } else {
    navbar.style.borderBottom = "";
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
#main-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}
#mainscreen {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#navbar-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 68.53px;
}
#navbar {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: #112D34;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 1;
}
#navbar #logo {
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
#navlinks ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
#navlinks ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
#play-area {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#play-area-overlay {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
#textbox,
#visualizer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
#textbox {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
#visualizer {
  background: indianred;
}
#playlist-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<section id="main-container">
  <div id="navbar-container">
    <div id="navbar">
      <div id="logo">
        <h4><SPAN>V</SPAN>ibe<span>C</span>iti</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="navlinks">
        <ul>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Playlist</li>
          <li>Gallery</li>
          <li>Portfolio</li>
          <li>
            <button>Contact</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainscreen">
    <div id="play-area">
      <div id="play-area-overlay">
        <div id="textbox">
          <h2>Welcolme.</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="visualizer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="playlist-container">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank  you, I did use the flexbox to layout my navbar. I thought I set my "play-area-overlay" to flex as well which I didn't. Quite an embarrassing mistake on my part. Everything is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

try this..!

```
#textbox h2 {
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
margin: 0px;
}
```